# Display date as Month/Year but validate and save as full date mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, model, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a date stored in the database as a standard DateTime format.  I get the value, and display it in a form field as mm/yyyy.  My partial view displays via this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.opinionDate, new { @Value = Model.opinionDate.ToString("MM/yyyy"), @readonly = "readonly" })
```

I have bootstrap-datepicker wired up to the date field.  It is set to only allow selecting the month and year.

My jQuery model validation is failing as it does not look like a date.  How can I validate this value?  Can I modify the value (adding in 01 for the day) before the validation occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Since your field is readonly and the datepicker is already giving you the value you want, perhaps you can either not validate the field at all or validate it as a string instead. Then if you need the extra layer of validation, do so in the controller. Check out the documentation for [validating dates](http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method). If you validate as a string you can do a quick check to make sure you have the appropriate number of characters:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({  
    rules: {    
        opinionDate: {      
            required: true,
            rangelength: [4, 5]    
               }  
           }});
```

This checks to see if the string is between 4-5 characters long ("1/15" or "01/15"). Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting an error, apparently in my model since I'm trying to read a DateTime value but use it like a string.  

    Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. You have a couple of options to make that string into datetime. In your controller you could concatenate the day portion of the date as a placeholder and convert it to a string, using something like DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date) per the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)

Comment: You could also make that happen in your model: `public string date_from_view { get; set;}` which stores the string and `public DateTime date { get { return Convert.ToDateTime("01/" + date_from_view); }}` which converts the string to a datetime and stores it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by parsing the value coming in and out of the database via my controller.  My model treats the value as a string.  So far so good.  I wasn't able to get the validation working above, but I can deal with that later.  Since this is an Intranet app, using the date picker is enough to get a clean date for now.